# How to check is S3 service is available or not in AWS via CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have options to :

```
1. Copy file/object to another S3 location or local path (cp)
2. List S3 objects (ls)
3. Create bucket (mb) and move objects to bucket (mv)
4. Remove a bucket (rb) and remove an object (rm)
5. Sync objects and S3 prefixes
```

and many more.

But before using the commands, we need to check if S3 service is available in first place. How to do it?

Is there a command like :

```
aws S3 -isavailable
```

and we get response like

```
0 - S3 is available, I can go ahead upload object/create bucket etc.
1 - S3 is not availble, you can't upload object etc. ?
```

Comment: Presumably you can check the exit code from running any command via awscli.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I would like to check the availability of service first and if it is not, I would like to send a message to my Queue System.

Answer (score 3):

**You should assume that Amazon S3 is available.** If there is a problem with S3, you will receive an error when making a call with the Amazon CLI.

If you are particularly concerned, then add a simple CLI command first, eg `aws s3 ls` and throw away the results. But that's really the same concept. Or, you could use the `--dry-run` option available on many commands that simply indicates **whether you would have had sufficient permissions to make the request**, but doesn't actually run the request.

It is more likely that you will have an error in your configuration (eg wrong region, credentials not valid) than S3 being down.